# Enviar datos mediantre POST a API y mostrar respuesta en PHP

Tags: php, json, api, post, curl

tengo un problemilla, soy algo nuevo en esto de PHP y no logro hacer que algo funcione.

Les explico.

Tengo acceso a una API de envios (Paquetería), la misma me da la posibilidad de rastrear los paquetes mediante un número de guia o un ID de envío y me devuelve en JSON la respuesta con el estado del envío.

He hecho un pequeño script que realice las funciones de rastreo pero no logro hacer que me muestre ni el estado "principal" ni los "sub-eventos".

La petición se envía mediante POST y la respuesta luce así:

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "enviaya_shipment_number": "N9T30TAC",
    "carrier_tracking_number": "9878401142",
    "channel": "Api",
    "estimated_delivery_date": null,
    "expected_delivery_date": "12/01/2022",
    "pickup_date": "2021-12-30T10:39:11-06:00",
    "shipment_status": "En tránsito",
    "event_code": 151,
    "event_description": "Llegada al Centro de DHL",
    "event": "Llegada",
    "status_code": 14,
    "sub_event_code": null,
    "sub_event": null,
    "sub_event_description": null,
    "checkpoints": [
        {
            "code": "PU",
            "description": "Envío recibido",
            "date": "2022-01-03T12:12:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MEXICO CITY-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "PL",
            "description": "Procesado",
            "date": "2022-01-03T14:07:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MEXICO CITY-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "DF",
            "description": "Salida",
            "date": "2022-01-03T14:08:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MEXICO CITY-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "AF",
            "description": "Llegada",
            "date": "2022-01-03T15:30:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MEXICO CITY HUB-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "PL",
            "description": "Procesado",
            "date": "2022-01-03T18:55:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MEXICO CITY HUB-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "DF",
            "description": "Salida",
            "date": "2022-01-03T19:04:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MEXICO CITY HUB-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "AF",
            "description": "Llegada",
            "date": "2022-01-03T20:55:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "QUERETARO-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "PL",
            "description": "Procesado",
            "date": "2022-01-03T22:03:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "QUERETARO-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "DF",
            "description": "Salida",
            "date": "2022-01-03T22:31:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "QUERETARO-MEX"
        },
        {
            "code": "AR",
            "description": "Llegada",
            "date": "2022-01-04T01:52:00.000-06:00",
            "postal_code": null,
            "city": null,
            "country_code": null,
            "country": null,
            "comments": "MERIDA-MEX"
        }
    ]
}
```

Entonces hice un formulario en HTML para que el cliente envíe los datos, es algo muy sencillo:

```
<form action="track.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form-app">
<fieldset class="row">

<!-- Heading -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h3 class="legend">Rastreo de Paquetes</h3>
</div>


<!-- Select List -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group required-control">
        <label  class="control-label" for="carrier">Paquetería</label>
        <select id="carrier" name="carrier" data-alias=""  class="form-control" required  >
            <option value="UPS" >UPS</option>
            <option value="Redpack" >Redpack</option>
            <option value="Estafeta" >Estafeta</option>
            <option value="DHL" >DHL</option>
            <option value="99 Minutos" >99 Minutos</option>
            <option value="FedEx" >FedEx</option>
            <option value="iVoy" >iVoy</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Number -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group required-control">
        <label  class="control-label" for="number">Número de guía o ID de Envío</label>
        <input type="text" id="shipment" name="shipment" value="" data-alias="" data-integer-only="true"  class="form-control"  required>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-action">
        <button type="submit" id="button_1" name="button_1" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto a su vez envía al archivo que en teoría conecta con la API mediante cURL enviando los datos, recibiendo la respuesta y decodificando el JSON

```
<?php
include_once "key.php";
$shipment_number=$_POST["shipment"];
$carrier=$_POST["carrier"];

 //SEND REQUEST post TO api AND DECODE JSON RESPONSE
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/api/v1/trackings");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "carrier=".$carrier."&shipment_number=".$shipment_number);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     "api_key: ".$API_KEY
 ));
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 $respuesta = json_decode($response);
 

//Show the response on HTML format with tables
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Estado del Envío</td><td>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Evento</td><td>".$respuesta->event_description."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Guía</td><td>".$respuesta->carrier_tracking_number."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>ID de Envio</td><td>".$respuesta->enviaya_shipment_number."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Fecha de envio</td><td>".$respuesta->pickup_date."</td></tr>";

//Show subevents on HTML format with tables
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Evento</td><td>Descripción</td><td>Fecha</td></tr>";
foreach ($respuesta->subevents as $subevent) {
  echo "<tr><td>".$subevent->event."</td><td>".$subevent->description."</td><td>".$subevent->date."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Sin embargo algo va evidentemente mal ya que me muestra las celdas vacías es decir no muestra ningún dato.

Segun el

```
 var_dump($respuesta);
```

La clave API es incorrecta pero ya verifique y esta bien.

Comment: Probablemente [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) te está devolviendo un arreglo asociativo en lugar de objeto. Intenta con `$respuesta = json_decode($response, false);` y, en caso de que sigas obteniendo error, muestra en pantalla la respuesta obtenida con `var_dump($response);` que, seguramente, te dará pistas para solucionar el problema.

Comment: @Triby He hecho lo que me comentaste del var_dump y en efecto me dice que la clave API es inválida, pero ya revise por todos lados y en apariencia esta bien, la clave es correcta, que podrá ser?

Comment: Revisa que la `API_KEY` se está enviando de forma correcta, ¿debe ir como encabezado y el nombre en minúsculas? ¿Necesitas encabezados adicionales?

Comment: @Triby La verdad no lo se, reutilice el código de otra API que parecia ser igual pero quizá no deba ir como encabezado, pero entonces no sabría como enviarla, soy muy nuevo en esto mira esta es la documentación https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/docs/api#shipment-tracking

Comment: @Triby Gracias a ti encontré la respuesta pero que tonto fui no debe pasarse la clave como cabecera si no como un parámetro más, ahora ya me muestra la información. Solo que ahora debo resolver como mostrar los demás "checkpoints" en una tabla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He logrado dar con la respuesta:

En primer lugar pasaba la clave API como cabecera y debia pasarse como un parametro más, y luego he logrado hacer que me muestre los checkpoints en una tabla, el código completo es:

```
<?php
include_once "key.php";
$shipment_number=$_POST["shipment"];
$carrier=$_POST["carrier"];

$params = array(
  "api_key" => $API_KEY,
  "carrier" => $carrier,
  "shipment_number" => $shipment_number
);
$headers = array(
  "api_key=".$API_KEY
);
curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://envios.corporativomarva.mx/api/v1/trackings",
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params),
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$respuesta = json_decode($response);
 

//Show the response on HTML format with tables
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Estado del Envío</td><td>".$respuesta->shipment_status."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Evento</td><td>".$respuesta->event_description."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Guía</td><td>".$respuesta->carrier_tracking_number."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>ID de Envio</td><td>".$respuesta->enviaya_shipment_number."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Fecha de envio</td><td>".$respuesta->pickup_date."</td></tr>";

//Show checkpoints data in a table
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Checkpoint</td><td>Fecha</td><td>Código</td><td>Descripción</td><td>Ciudad</td><td>Estado</td><td>País</td><td>Comentarios</td></tr>";
foreach($respuesta->checkpoints as $checkpoint){
  echo "<tr><td>".$checkpoint->description."</td><td>".$checkpoint->date."</td><td>".$checkpoint->code."</td><td>".$checkpoint->description."</td><td>".$checkpoint->city."</td><td>".$checkpoint->state."</td><td>".$checkpoint->country."</td><td>".$checkpoint->comments."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```